# Return jquery object to normal string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script.

```
var myDiv = `<span class=name">mytext<span>`;

//change font size for $(myDiv)
$(myDiv).find('span.name').css('font-size','3px');

// but myDiv is not changed....
var html = `<div>{$myDiv}</div>`;
```

maybe I need the way to return the change of `$(myDiv)` to `myDiv`

is there any good way??

Comment: Create a myDiv jquery object, make change and then use innerHTML to stringify it.

Comment: Also find() won't work when the element you want is at root level of the html string. Use `filter()` for root elements

Comment: Please review this link https://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are so close!

Your html string is not valid (require close tag, `"` for class name).

The `.find('span.name')` function return "nothing", because `span` now is root and the root element just has a text node (`mytext`).

Just wrap you `span` into a `div` object, then do as you do to access to your `span` element. In this case you append style attribute for the element.

```
const myDiv = `<span class="name">mytext</span>`; // I corrected you html string

const $ele = $('<div>').append(myDiv); // wrap your html string into a div element, now div is root

$ele.find('span.name').css('font-size', '3px'); // append style attr

const html = `<div>${$ele.html()}</div>`; // html() mean inside html string (inside div)
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a answer as I don't have enough points to comment. In your code - you have NOT quoted the class properly - **class=name"** This needs to be fixed.

Other than that - as of now, myDiv is a string - it is not getting added to the DOM - that code seems to be missing in your question above.

Once you add the string in myDiv to DOM - you will be able to do other changes
For example:

```
const $div = $(myDiv).appendTo('body');
$div.css('font-size','3px');
```

I'm hoping you will be able to use const/let instead of var.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Also I need to understand the const/let

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var has a very good details